# Numbers range split-up based on input range in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table (table1) with data as

```
SlNo NumberStart NumberEnd   Volume
1     101              110    10 
2     301              301     1
```

My jquery input is
Number of volume is requested as

```
Volume: 3

NumberStart          NumberEnd
  301                   301
  103                   103
```

When I filter the inputs in table1 data,the select statement result should be split as below

```
 NumberStart     NumberEnd      isSplitted    Volume
        301              301            Yes       1
        101              102            Yes       2
        103              103            Yes       1 
        104              110            No        7
```

So my requested volume 3 is splitted.

Could you please anyone share the SELECT statement for the above?

Comment: What is the logic for `is_splitted`?

Comment: If the row is break as of requested then is_Splitted = yes.                                 here   range 101 - 110    is break as 101 -102 and  103-110

Answer (score 0):

The exact logic your are trying to implement is a little vague.  You seem to be taking "initial" parts out of each range in `table1`, based on `table2`.  For the parts that match, `is_splitted = 1`.

The following returns the results you have specified:

```
select t1.NumberStart, t2.NumberEnd, 1 as is_splitted, t2.NumberEnd - t1.NumberStart as volume
from table1 t1  join
     table2 t2
     on t1.NumberStart = t2.NumberStart
union all
select t2.NumberStart + 1, t1.NumberEnd, 0 as is_splitted, t1.NumberEnd - t2.NumberEnd as volume
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t1.NumberStart = t2.NumberStart
where t2.NumberEnd <> t1.NumberEnd;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ed0073184743db38dfe8e32ce8d2e66c) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Ref: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/5f67a/54)

Please, follow below SQL query:

```
create table stock(SlNo integer, NumberStart integer, NumberEnd integer, Volume integer);
```

> insert into stock values (1,101,110,10),(2,301,301,1);

```
Where you pass your start and end limit of volume like:

  select 101 as req_start_no, 102 req_end_no
  union all
  select 301 as req_start_no, 301 req_end_no
  ....
```

> Final QUERY:

```
select R.req_start_no, R.req_end_no, 'Yes' as isSplitted,
(R.req_end_no - R.req_start_no + 1) as req_volume
from stock s
left outer join (
  select 101 as req_start_no, 102 req_end_no
  union all
  select 103 as req_start_no, 103 req_end_no
  union all
  select 301 as req_start_no, 301 req_end_no
 ) as R on R.req_start_no >= s.NumberStart and R.req_end_no <= s.NumberEnd 
 where (R.req_end_no - R.req_start_no + 1) <=  s.volume 
union all
 select (max(R.req_start_no) + 1) as NumberStart, max(s.NumberEnd) as NumberEnd, 
 'No' as isSplitted,  
 avg(s.volume) - sum(R.volume) as req_volume
from stock s
left outer join (
  select 101 as req_start_no, 102 as req_end_no, (102 - 101 + 1) as volume
  union all
  select 103 as req_start_no, 103 as req_end_no, (103 - 103 + 1) as volume
  union all
  select 301 as req_start_no, 301 as req_end_no, (301 - 301 + 1) as volume
 ) as R on R.req_start_no >= s.NumberStart and R.req_end_no <= s.NumberEnd 
 group by s.SlNo
 having sum(R.volume) <  avg(s.volume)
```

Comment: You have to add another request slots in SQL query like:
  
  "select 101 as req_start_no, 102 req_end_no
  union all
  select 103 as req_start_no, 103 req_end_no
  union all
  select 301 as req_start_no, 301 req_end_no"

Comment: Should split automatic not hardcode.
Splitup based on my table1  and input request